# How do I connect R to someone else's MySql server?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I used the following code to connect R to my own MySQL server (i.e. localhost server).

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="root",password="********",dbname="try",host="localhost")

dbListTables(con) # to see what all tables the database has

#data(test) (shows error becuase its not yet in R, its still on server)

dbListFields(con, 'test')  #to see what all fields the table has

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM test") #data is still on the server

data <- fetch(rs, n = -1) #using fetch to bring data into R
```

Now I have to connect to someone else's MySQL server (i.e. their IP would be different, the server would be on their system/machine) to get the data from them.

So, what all details do I need and what all modification do I need to do in the code?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct host (remote server domain name or at a pinch, dotted IP address), user name and password as defined by the admin of the remote MySQL server.

Once that's set in `con <- dbConnect(...` everything should be the same.

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user="fred",password="********",dbname="try",host="yoursql.wherever.com")
```

Note you might have problems if your local network policy blocks any of the ports that MySQL uses.

Comment: I guess the question for me becomes `host="yoursql.wherever.com`, I am trying to connect to a database in my laptop and have struggled with how to find the instructions on which IP address to use(presuming I am suppose to use IP addr).  I can connect to mysql server on one laptop from another laptop over my home network by using the “Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi IPv6” from ipconfig in windows.  But when I am trying to access the same server from remote machine running in Putty I am unsuccessful, have tried every one of those IP addresses.  Thanks